# Understanding non-trivial conjugate points on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am studying Jacobi fields on Riemannian manifolds, and I am trying to construct a simple example of a point with a "non-trivial" conjugate point (one with multiplicity $m \in \{ 1, \ldots , n-2 \}$, where multiplicity measures the maximum number of linearly independent Jacobi fields satisfying $J(0)=0=J(t_0)$) to get a feel for what it would mean for a conjugate point to have non-trivial multiplicity.

It seems trivial to me to see that you can't construct such an example for a $2$-manifold, which implies that all conjugate points on $2$-manifolds have maximum multiplicity, meaning that conjugate points for $2$-manifolds are where nearby geodesics bump into one another. Please correct me if my reasoning here is faulty.

I'm trying to imagine/reason what might happen for a $3$-manifold. If the multiplicity of a particular conjugate point is $1$, then does this mean that geodesics will converge to a particular submanifold? I am finding it hard to get a geometric interpretation so any input on this would be helpful.

Comment: The north pole and south pole of the $n$-sphere are conjugate with multiplicity $n-1$, while no points of the $n$-torus are conjugate. You can make products of spheres and tori, to get some more examples: $S^p \times S^q$ has opposite points conjugate of multiplicity $(p-1)+(q-1)$. The north pole is conjugate to itself on the real projective $n$-space, with multiplicity $n-1$, and so we can make some more product examples. Complex and quaternionic projective spaces are also easy examples, and again products.